# Document created with window.open never reaches "complete" readyState

Tags: javascript

I'm opening a new window with window.open and I'm writing some html on it. The problem is that I load a script that does this:

```
if(document.readyState === "complete") {
    load_script();
}else{
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        load_script();
    });
}
```

But state never  gets to "complete" state and DOMcontentLoaded never fires... The strange thing is that this doesn't happen because there is stuff loading, no, everything loads perfectly untill this moment.

Is there a way to fallback this in case those things never fire? I thought of a timer, but doesn't feel very reliable...

Comment: writing stuff in it with document.write() ?

Comment: @epascarello yes, because with innerHTML (if I remember correctly) didn't execute scripts

Comment: Do you close the document?

Comment: @epascarello close the window? or what do you mean?

Comment: `winpop.document.open();winpop.document.write("cccccc"); winpop.document.close();`

Comment: Great, this worked! Would you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open and close the document when you write to it so it knows when it is done.

```
winpop.document.open();
winpop.document.write("cccccc");
winpop.document.close();
```

where `winpop` is the reference to the new window.

Comment: I was worried it will close the window, but it keep the window open. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What if you observe when the different events fire?

```
 document.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            load_script();
        } else {
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                load_script();
            });
        }
    }
```